# MySQL Alter huge table(change field type)

Tags: mysql, performance

So i have a table with `4 016 515 759` rows. I need to change the field type of my `address_id` field from `int` to `bigint`, also its a `FOREIGN KEY`.

I just tested this query:

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
ALTER TABLE `my_table` CHANGE address_id address_id bigint;
```

On a local table with `6 845 016` rows - it takes 14 minutes. I Guess on production this 4 billion rows will take a long time.

So question is: How to update this really fast and safe? or Should i copy `my_table` and do the `ALTER` on this copy and then raname it?

Because downtime will be very long.

Comment: default value of `address_id` is 0

Comment: `address_id not null default 0`

Comment: same result, about 14 minutes

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: This might be engine specific.

Altering a column in a much used table that has a foreign key... you're entering a world of hurt my friend.

If you do that on an environment that's actually being used at that time the whole table will be locked until your change is complete. Prepare for lock wait timeouts and even max connections errors. Depending on your situation a change of only a few minutes could mean downtime.

There are those who arcanely worked around it:

http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-online-schema-change.html

Be sure to read the parts about foreign keys.

So...

My personal method is to refrain from things like that and try to prevent it by oversizing any fields that **might ever** get too small and too important. Unsigned bigints on all numeric primary keys and such.

Once in a while, though, someone else just kicks in a huge alter table, everything clogs, we hit max connections. It's difficult to prevent that because a test won't fail that hard: A simple testing env doesn't have that much traffic.

The thing is: The inevitable mysql restart tends to revive the table **with** the new structure in no time.

Short version:

- Plan downtime
- Minimize client queries by turning stuff off
- Run the alter table
- Restart MySQL when you start getting bored